# C++ stream extraction operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

This is a question as to the philosophy (canonical design) of user-written C++ input stream extraction operators (>>).

Assume that on entry to the >> operator implementation (for a user-written class), the eof flag is already set for the input stream.

Should a user-written extraction operator (>>)

1. set the failure flag (because no instance of the desired object can be found)
2. should it just return to the caller with the eof flag still set.

If the second approach is used, it implies that the caller must always check the eof flag before any attempt is made to invoke the >> operator. The reason is that the >> operator might successfully extract an instance of the desired class and set the eof flag.

The original code follows. Based on the comments below, this code appears to be wrong. If eof is already set on input, the extraction operator will simply return with eof still set. It appears that if eof is set, but bad and fail are not set, then an extraction of a string should be done to set the fail bit. Of course, the fail bit can be set directly.

```
/* Implement the C/C++ >> (stream input) operator as a non-member 
   function */
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream& is, DecNumber &val) {
  DecContext  context{DecContext::defInit};
  uint32_t    status;
  /* The true value below prevents whitespace from being skipped */
  std::istream::sentry  s(is, true);
  std::string           inStr;
  /* Check if the input stream is in a good state. Just return to the
     caller if the input stremm is not in a good state. The caller
     must handle this condition. */
  if(!s) 
    return is; 
  /* Get a string from the input stream. This string is converted to 
     a DecNumber below. Just return to the caller if this step causes
     any stream related errors. Note that reaching the end of the 
     input is not a stream related error here. A decimal number might
     be the absolute last thing in the stream. */
  is >> inStr;
  if (is.bad() || is.fail())
    return is;
  /* Try to convert the string to a DecNumber using the default context
     value */
  decNumberFromString(val.getDecVal(), inStr.c_str(), context.getDecCont());
  status = context.DecContextGetStatus();
  /* Remove a few status bits we don't care about */
  status &= ~(DEC_Inexact + DEC_Rounded);
  if (status)
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); 
  return is;
}
```

Comment: Write up a [concise sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clarify what you'r actually asking for please! I've already been exhausting my close votes on this question as mentioned, but unless you show this in your question, it's keeping being either _too broad_, or actually _opinion based_.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, My intent was to obtain advice as to how the canonical forrm(s) of the stream extraction operator (>>) handle eof conditions that either exist on entry or occur while extraction is being done. A number of folks (including you) have been very helpful in addressing this question.

Comment: There's no _canonical forms_, but ***use cases*** you have for your custom overloads. Sorry c++ doesn't provide a _cooking recipe_, but flexibilty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement solution 1.

When in doubt, just look at what's already being done.  As you can see below, the fail bit is being set if we try to read from a stream in EOF state.

Note that EOF is not the only way to fail though.  Try setting `std::string vals = "52 43 A";` in the code below.

`failbit` should be set if **for any reason**, `operator>>` doesn't actually stream a value.  EOF is just one of those reasons.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_stream (std::istream & print_me, int const & i)
{
  std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
  std::ios_base::iostate bits = print_me.rdstate();

  std::cout << "good: " << (bits & std::ios_base::goodbit) << 
    ", bad: " << (bits & std::ios_base::badbit) << 
    ", fail: " << (bits & std::ios_base::failbit) <<
    ", eof: " << (bits & std::ios_base::eofbit) << "\n";

  std::cout << "\n----------------------------\n\n";
}

int main (void)
{
  std::string vals = "52 43";
  std::istringstream iss(vals);
  int i;

  iss >> i;
  print_stream (iss, i);
  iss >> i;
  print_stream (iss, i);
  iss >> i;
  print_stream (iss, i);
  iss >> i;
  print_stream (iss, i);

  return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
$ ./a.exe
i: 52
good: 0, bad: 0, fail: 0, eof: 0

----------------------------

i: 43
good: 0, bad: 0, fail: 0, eof: 2

----------------------------

i: 43
good: 0, bad: 0, fail: 4, eof: 2

----------------------------

i: 43
good: 0, bad: 0, fail: 4, eof: 2

----------------------------
```

---

Note that the typical read pattern loop is some variation of...

```
while (input >> var >> var2 >> var3)
{
  // failbit is not set.  All reads succeeded.
  // Do Stuff
}
```

If you need to detect whether the fail happened at some point during reading of multiple values then yea, you need to be a little more sophisticated and do some testing like...

```
while (true)
{
  if (input >> var)
  {
    // We successfully read first value
    if (input >> var2 >> var3)
    {
      // We succesfully read all the values!
      // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
      ErrorLog ("Partial line read!");
      break;
    }
  else
  {
    // Nothing else to read
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the overloaded extraction operator?? Your answer doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: QuestionC your code example and comments provided the insights I was missing in my attempts to implement a stream extraction operator.  πάντα ῥεῖ your efforts in this matter are to be commended even if I don't entirely agree.

Answer (score 1):

> *"If the second approach is used, it implies that the caller **must always check the eof flag** before any attempt is made to invoke the >> operator."*

No, why do you think they need to do so?

> *"Should a user-written extraction operator (>>) set the failure flag (because no instance of the desired object can be found) or should it just return to the caller with the eof flag still set."*

The latter option of course, you're not supposed to manage stream states in overloaded extraction operators, unless you add your own validation rules (e.g. for expecting specific character patterns with the `std::string` field). It will usually be done correctly with the sub extraction operations that the overloaded operator uses.

Supposed you have something like follows:

```
struct MyType {
    std::string field1;
    int field2;
    double field3;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyType& myinstance) {
      is >> field1;
      is >> field2;
      is >> field3;
      return is;
}
```

Each of the extractions will set the fields to their default constructed values, in case the `operator>>()` fails, because the stream is in `eof()` state, and the value will be left in it's original state for the field that was attempted to extract.

I actually don't see a need to have any additional check for `eof()` or setting the stream to `fail()` state in your overloaded input operator.

The client (caller) will simply use something like e.g.

```
 std::ifstream input("MyFile.txt");
 std::vector<MyType> allObjects;
 MyType curObject;
 while(input >> curObject) {
      allObjects.push_back(curObject);
 }
```

You see, no need to check for `input.eof()` anywhere.

Comment: An overloaded extraction operator is not necessarily just an aggregate of extractions of simpler members. It may need to do some custom validation. And if that validation fails, the fail bit should be set on the stream.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Well, the OP should clarify more about what they're actually doing then. I've already started out close voting that question as _primarily opinion based_ (retracted later). OP just talks about handling `eof()` state, in this case it's certainly not necessary to manipulate the input stream state. Custom validation on an operational `std::istream`, is a valid reason to manipulate the stream state from the overloaded operator. Having `eof()` state, isn't.

Comment: I was really just responding to one specific point in your answer, *"you're not supposed to manage stream states in overloaded extraction operators, it will be done correctly with the sub extraction operations that the overloaded operator uses."* -- That is, imo, as per my earlier comment, wrong. Irrespective of whatever the OP is doing.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, Why would a user need to check for eof before and after using a C++ input stream extraction operator (>>)? Because otherwise, the user will have no way of telling if the eof state existed before the >> operator was used or if the eof state occurred as a consequence of obtaining a value (quite possibly valid) from the input stream using the >> operator.

Comment: @PeterSchaeffer Does that really matter for a user, why extraction actually failed? If it was because of `eof`, or actually an extraction failure when parsing the stream? The stream goes to `fail` state in either way, unless you want to do extra validation on successfully parsed fields from the standard extraction operators.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, It certainly could matter to a user, why extraction failed. For example, bad input (causing an extraction failure) is typically handled quite differently, than simply reaching the end of the input stream. My original concern was how to tell the difference between an eof condition that existed before an extraction operator (>>) was used, versus an eof condition that occurred as a consequence of an extraction operator (>>). The only way I could see to do this (tell the difference between the two cases) was to test for eof before the extraction.

Comment: @PeterSchaeffer _My original concern was how to tell the difference between an eof ..._ `eof()` just keeps to be true for such case, there's no specific need to set `fail()` state additionally.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, QuestionC suggests that this question be resolved in a different way. If eof is set before an extraction (using >>), then a failure flag should be set. This could be done manually (setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)) or implicitly by using the extraction operator (>>) with a std::string. Since my code uses >> to obtain a std::string before attempting validation, this makes considerable sense.

Comment: @PeterSchaeffer _" QuestionC suggests ..."_ They're most probably wrong. Even if this is seemingly your way, you want to go about this.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, "Each of the extractions will set the fields to their default constructed values". That's interesting. The code sample provided by QuestionC seems to show that fields are left unchanged in failure cases.

Comment: @PeterSchaeffer Sorry, yes they're left with their original state. I'm going to fix this. Doesn't have a big impact about the real points of your question here.